VirtualBox/vagrant VM can't mount shared folders after unexpected host reboot
Context: Windows 11 host, CentOS 7 guest, Vagrant box that has been mostly unmodified for a long time. (I'm gradually building a brand new Debian VM, but it's not ready for use yet and I don't currently have any time to work on it.)
Issue: A few days ago while I was asleep and my VM was running, my PC rebooted for some unknown reason (not a Windows update - I guess something crashed). Now, I get the following error trying to do vagrant up:
Vagrant was unable to mount VirtualBox shared folders. This is usually
because the filesystem "vboxsf" is not available. This filesystem is
made available via the VirtualBox Guest Additions and kernel module.
Please verify that these guest additions are properly installed in the
guest. This is not a bug in Vagrant and is usually caused by a faulty
Vagrant box. For context, the command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000,_netdev vagrant /vagrant

The error output from the command was:

/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such device

In SSH, I looked for what it said was the problem. /sbin/mount.vboxsf is a symbolic link to /usr/lib64/VBoxGuestAdditions/mount.vboxsf, which appears to exist:
[root@7and7](02:32:55)[~]$ ls -l /usr/lib64/VBoxGuestAdditions/mount.vboxsf
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 19152 Sep 13  2016 /usr/lib64/VBoxGuestAdditions/mount.vboxsf*

Prior to the error, it does warn me that my Guest Additions version and VirtualBox version don't match (GA 5.1.6 vs. VBox 6.1). But it has had that warning for years with no problems, so that seems unlikely to be the cause of the current issue. I know this isn't a perfect VM - I just need it to run.
I have daily backups of all files on my PC for the last month, so I tried restoring an earlier backup of the folder that contains my .vbox and .vmdk files, but I got the same error. If there are other things I should try with backups (other files, etc.), let me know. I'm not sure whether the backup I picked was while the VM was running or not - I hope not, but I don't remember for sure. And I don't know if that matters.
Next, I decided to try following some online answers (albeit old) that say to run vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest and then vagrant halt and vagrant up to let the plugin install Guest Additions. The plugin installed okay, but when I did vagrant up, I got a new error earlier in the boot process:
[7and7] GuestAdditions versions on your host (6.1.36) and guest (5.1.6) do not match.
Loaded plugins: priorities
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Name or service not known"

Yup, that mirrorlist no longer exists. It goes on with suggestions clearly generated by yum about how to deal with a repo that isn't working and then concludes with: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64 The boot continues for a little bit, then gives the same protest and yum suggestions again, then gives up. I don't know what repo it's looking for ("os" is not enough of a clue for me) nor where a copy might be found, but I guess CentOS7 is just too old for that plugin.
Update #1:
Next, I tried to follow https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#additions-linux to use the VBoxGuestAdditions.iso to install the matching version of Guest Additions. Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD Image complains that I don't have an optical drive at all, but with the VM was powered off, I was able to use Settings -> Storage to add it to my virtual IDE Controller. So at the moment, it looks like this:

That sure seems like I have an optical drive with that .iso in it. Then the manual page says:


Change to the directory where your CD-ROM drive is mounted and run the following command as root:
sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run


But viewing via SSH, either it's not actually mounted or I don't know where to find it. find / -name VBoxLinuxAdditions.run returns no hits. /mnt has one subdirectory called virtualbox, but it's empty. /dev/sr0 looks promising, but mount /dev/sr0 says: mount: can't find /dev/sr0 in /etc/fstab. At that point it's getting out of my league - fstab doesn't look like the sort of file I should try to muck with.
The thing is, this was working until a few days ago, even with the version mismatch. If I could just get back to how it was a week ago (or even a year ago!), i.e. mounting shared folders without error, I would be very happy.
